# No R, como calcular a média de uma coluna baseado em outra?

Tags: r

Tenho a seguinte tabela XLSX:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso calcular a média da coluna SP500 para cada ano. Fiz com 'mean(nomedatabela$SP500)' e encontrei a média total. Agora eu preciso da média por cada ano. Alguém sabe como posso fazer?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há várias maneiras de fazer o que quer.

**Mas primeiro os dados.**

```
set.seed(941)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis

Data <- c("3/1/2005", "4/1/2005", "5/1/2005", "6/1/2005",
          "14/2/2006", "15/2/2006", "16/2/2006", "17/2/2006",
          "6/3/2007", "7/3/2007", "8/3/2007", "9/3/2007",
          "13/2/2008", "14/2/2008", "15/2/2008", "16/2/2008")
SP500 <- round(runif(length(Data), 900, 1400), 2)

nomedatabela <- data.frame(Data, SP500)
```

Como vamos precisar do ano, transforma-se a coluna `Data` num vetor de class `Date`, com a função base `as.Date`. Depois, para obter o `ano`, vou usar o pacote `lubridate`.

```
nomedatabela$Data <- as.Date(nomedatabela$Data, "%d/%m/%Y")
ano <- lubridate::year(nomedatabela$Data)
```

**Agora as médias.**

A função `tapply` agrupa o primeiro argumento por um fator e calcula um valor da função `FUN` para cada grupo. O resultado é um vetor.

```
tapply(nomedatabela$SP500, ano, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#    2005     2006     2007     2008 
#1213.207 1092.210 1174.513 1124.352
```

A função `aggregate` também agrupa e calcula um valor da função `FUN` para cada grupo mas o resultado é um objeto de classe `data.frame`. Para definir os grupos, vou usar a interface de fórmulas de `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(SP500 ~ ano, nomedatabela, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#   ano    SP500
#1 2005 1213.207
#2 2006 1092.210
#3 2007 1174.513
#4 2008 1124.352
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! Apenas por curiosidade, supondo que minha tabela possua mais entradas que essas, exemplo: 800 linhas de data. Existe alguma forma mais rápida para definir 'Data' ou eu teria que entrar com as 800 linhas na mão, como no seu código?

Comment: @VictorOliveira Não percebo, entrar com as 800 linhas como? Isso não está nalgum ficheiro? Se não está, bom, entre com elas só uma vez e grave em disco! Se as datas são consecutivas, pode usar `seq.Date`.

Answer (score 2):

## Estou criando uma tabela para explicar oq estou fazendo

```
Data <- c("3/1/2005", "4/1/2005", "5/1/2005", "6/1/2005",
      "14/2/2006", "15/2/2006", "16/2/2006", "17/2/2006",
      "6/3/2007", "7/3/2007", "8/3/2007", "9/3/2007",
      "13/2/2008", "14/2/2008", "15/2/2008", "16/2/2008")
SP500 <- runif(length(Data), 900, 1400)
```

## Ao inves de fazer t <- data.frame(Data, SP500) leia a base dada usando read.alguma(dependendo da extenso q vc esta usando).

## Daqui para baixo estou usando pacote dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
 t <- tibble(Data, SP500)
```

## Estou acresentando o ano

```
a<- as.Date(t$Data, "%d/%m/%Y")
ano <- tibble(ano=lubridate::year(a))
```

## Achando a media pedida

```
base <- cbind(t,ano)   
base2 <- base %>% group_by(ano) %>% summarise(media=mean(SP500))
```

A unica diferenca entra a minha solucao e a solucao de cima e que estou usando o pacote dplyr para calular a media e criar tibbles